# Сохранить результат запроса в переменную

Tags: c++, sql, qt, запрос

вопрос заключается в следующем:необходимо сохранить результат запроса SQL в переменную maxS,и далее вывести на экран используя функцию setText(работа с Qt Framework),однако нечего не выводиться,не могу понять почему не сохраняет результат.Код:

```
 QSqlQuery query;
    query.prepare("SELECT  MAX(salary) FROM worker");
    query.exec();
            if(query.next()){
                maxS=query.value(3).toString();
                     }
                ui->label_11->setText(maxS)
```

Comment: Почему 3 в `query.value(3)`? У вас ведь только один результат из запроса приходит

Answer (score 3):

Запрашивайте из запроса первый элемент (индекс 0), т.к. из sql у вас придет только одно значение:

```
QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT MAX(salary) FROM worker");
query.exec();
if (query.next()) {
    maxS = query.value(0).toString();
}
ui->label_11->setText(maxS)
```

Подробнее про [QSqlQuery::value(int index)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#value)

Comment: Спасибо,исправил ,все заработало

Comment: @ЖеняМедяник, пожалуйста :) Отметьте ответ :)

Comment: @ЖеняМедяник  Если ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour